# Как разделить ssd и hdd

Tags: windows-10, hdd, ос, ssd, kubuntu

Есть ноутбук с SSD и HDD. Хочу поставить на него Kubuntu, разделив SSD и HDD пополам, чтобы получилось так: Первая половина SSD и HDD - Windows 10, Вторая половина SSD и HDD - Kubuntu. Как это стоит сделать?

Comment: Подозреваю что никак, размазывать загрузочный раздел по двум устройствам это слишком необычно

Comment: @andreymal
А можно просто на вторую половину SSD установить Kubuntu, и вторую часть HDD настроить так, чтобы Kubuntu могла работать с ней ?

Comment: Можно, просто создайте нужные вам разделы в нужном расположении и количестве

Comment: @andreymal
Спасибо, так и сделаю